# Elasticsearch - Take full snapshot using the snapshot api

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Is there an option to take full snapshot using the ES snapshot api. we would like to take full snapshot every 3 days.

Comment: By "full" you mean as opposed to "incremental"? What's the point?

Comment: We would like to take a two pronged approach, full snapshot every x no of days and incremental every 1 hour after the full snapshot. When we need to restore, it would be restoring full snapshot + the incremental snapshots taken until the next full snapshot. It will help us reduce the no of files to maintain and also not risk us to live with one full backup file. We also want to purge the old backups, older than 30 days.

Comment: Given the way ES makes its snapshots, it doesn't really make sense. Full or incremental are blended and you  don't really need to care.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html

I used to do something the same in my previous company where we had a lambda trigger the backup every week via cron and a Full backup used to happen of all Documents and indexes. I have thought tried to restore once which failed the first time, but the second time it worked though, the issue was the instance was small and it needed a bigger one to restore the data, so please those setting as well.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Will this approach work for both full and incremental snapshots? Here are more details of our strategy. "We would like to take a two pronged approach, full snapshot every x no of days and incremental every 1 hour after the full snapshot. When we need to restore, it would be restoring full snapshot + the incremental snapshots taken until the next full snapshot. It will help us reduce the no of files to maintain and also not risk us to live with one full backup file. We also want to purge the old backups, older than 30 days."

Comment: Yes, you can extend the same for increment and full backup, but you would require to have you written in such a way that let's say every Sunday you take a full backup and then do increment on top of the same snapshot, and later when you want a new full backup you change the snapshot name. For Deleting the Snapshot again some custom script would be required, but make sure to call them via ES API itself.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, the snapshot name change is the trick. It helps us to achieve what we want.